# How to Inject produces again

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, java-ee-7

Using javaee beans, is there possibility to inject properties again if they are, for example, null?

My simplified code:

**Service** makes rest request to *another* service, and it get host property from a **PropertyProduces** that takes it from a third *config* service. For example, when I first time making **RestService.call()**, *config* service is disabled, so it return host=null. I am not able to  *callAnotherService* properly, this is fine. Then *config* service became enabled, but when I make second **RestService.call()**, *host* is already null and it even do not want to get to **PropertyProduces.produceString**

Can I somehow intercept usage of *host* property, check if it is null and force it to inject from Produces again?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Service {
    @Property
    private final String host;

    public void callAnotherService() {
        callRestMethod(host)
    }
}
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PropertyProduces {

    @Inject
    private Config config;

    @Property
    @Produces
    public String produceString(InjectionPoint ip) {
        return this.config.getString(ip.getMember().getName());
    }
}
```

```
@Path("/")
@ApplicationScoped
public class RestService {
    @Inject
    private Service service;
  
    @POST
    @Path("/call")
    public Response call(Request request)
    {
        this.service.callAnotherService();
    }
}
```

I know I can change class **Service** to @RequestScoped, so at different rest requests will be created different **Service** instances and host will be produces everytime. But is there another posibility, somehow changing PropertyProduces or making Interceptors?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use dynamic bean selection on your Service class:

```
 @Inject
 @Property
 Instance<String> instance;
```

and then in your Service method you can do:

```
public void callAnotherService() {
     String host = instance.get();
     callRestMethod(host)
}
```

More references at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html